# Call function in other frame

Tags: javascript, frames, frameset

I've got frameset having two frames. I want to add a function and call it (passing some arguments) in frame 0 from frame 1, and for the function to continue after reloading frame 1.
I've managed to call the function but after reloading the frame from which the call was made the function stops.


If I'm not clear, here is an example:
Let's say I have frames 'top' and 'bottom'. From the script called in bottom I add a function, that alerts a number and increments it, to the top. I also setInterval that function. When I do that the function is called, but when I location.replace the function stops. 
How can I deal with that?

Edit: 
Mu guess is that I call the function incorrectly, and then it somehow loses reference.

Comment: can you post your code ? It might be helpful

Comment: It's quite complex and it has been changing a lot since I've started to implement this. I want for the function to 'run in background'. So instead of frame it might be a popup window, but I didn't have luck with it either.